# Secure SignalR web socket calls fails with apparent routing error

Tags: asp.net, authentication, websocket, signalr

I am helping an internal company project that is writing an ASP.NET Api and a React client, supporting secure SignalR traffic. My role has been to secure the SignalR negotiation, slapping an `[Authorize]` attribute on the API SignalR hub class and make sure no unauthorized SignalR clients are let in.

This all works fine and I can see the entire negotiate request comes through with a 200 OK response. But then, checking the Chrome dev tool console, we see that subsequent web socket requests fail, and that it seems ASP.NET can't properly route the traffic to the correct hub and endpoint:

[image]

> We do not see this problem if we simply remove hub security by removing the hub class declarion `[Authorize]` attribute. Obviously, that is not acceptable, but it might be a clue to why the ASP.NET SignalR routing mechanism fails.

We are no experts in ASP.NET SignalR so any hints on what to look for would be appreciated. From how we understand it, only the initial HTTP negotiate request actually triggers the ASP.NET middleware pipe, which is where our custom company authentication happens.

After the successful negotiate round trip we don't seem to be able to catch any traffic via middleware so I assume web socket traffic is handled differently by ASP.NET?

This is the API side setup right now (CORS config is deliberately too liberal as we get things working):

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.RegisterKeyVault();
builder.RegisterOmniaDatabase();
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddSignalR();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowAll",
        builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000", "https://omnia-tp-test.azurewebsites.net", "https://omnia.company.com")
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowCredentials());
});
builder.Services.AddCompanyWebApiAuthorization();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IDataService, DataService>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IVisitCosmosDataService, VisitCosmosDataService>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IUserCosmosDataService, UserCosmosDataService>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IBlobDataService, BlobDataService>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<ITiDataService, TiDataService>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IMaterialDataService, MaterialDataService>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IInstalledBaseDataService, InstalledBaseDataService>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IAssetHelper, AssetHelper>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IPictureHelper, PictureHelper>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IVisitMetricService, VisitMetricService>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<ICustomerService, CustomerService>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<ITelemetryService, TelemetryService>();
builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(builder.Configuration["APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING"]);

var mappingConfig = new MapperConfiguration(mc => { mc.AddProfile(new AutomapperProfile()); });
mappingConfig.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
builder.Services.AddSingleton(mappingConfig.CreateMapper());

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseCors("AllowAll");
app.UseCompanyWebDiagnostics();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseCompanyAuthentication(app.Environment);
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.TrackLifetimeEvents();
app.MapHub<VisitHub>("/hubs/visit");
app.Run();
```

Comment: Auth runs on *both* the negotiate call and the websocket call. Depending on what your auth code is doing you might need to add support for auth in the query string for the websocket connection. See https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-8.0#built-in-jwt-authentication

Comment: To investigate and learn I injected a small middleware as the first in the MW pipe, and it's not getting invoked by the web socket traffic that happens after the negotiate. How is auth happening for web socket traffic?

Comment: A websocket request is a "normal" http request until you call `HttpContext.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync()`